# HP P440AR raid controller on G8 server

Tags: raid, hp

I've just bought a HP DL360 gen8 server with sata controller. I will change it with a SAS controller. But, i still have a little budget for it, and I am wondering if it supports the HP P440AR raid card that comes from a Gen9 server to reach 12g. Did someone gained experience about it, or I have to be stuck at 6g interface speed?

Comment: There's no need to go to 12G in this case. Are you sure your server doesn't have an onboard P420i?

Comment: I well, i wished i could pimp it up to 12g. Unfortuntely G9 or higher are still to expansive (for domestic use).
No, there is no p420i but b110i sata. My last money will go to buy that.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The P440AR isn't supported in a DL360 Gen8 sorry.